# PHP MySQL slow query access

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a table in my database :

[image]

And I'm using MySQL to insert/update/create info however the time it takes to execute queries is slow example:

First when a user runs my app it verifies they can use it by retrieving all IPs from the db with

```sql
SELECT IP FROM user_info
```

Then using a while loop if the IP is in the db do another query:

```php
"SELECT Valid FROM user_info WHERE IP='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'""
```

If Valid is 1 then they can use it otherwise they can't however if their IP is not found in the db it creates a new entry for them using

```php
"INSERT INTO user_info (IP,First) VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".date("Y/m/d") ."')")"
```

Now this first script has finished it accesses another - this one was supposed to update the db every minute however i don't think i can accomplish that now ; the update query is this:

```php
"UPDATE user_info SET Name='".$Name."', Status='".$Status."', Last='".$Last."', Address='".$Address."' WHERE IP='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'")"
```

All together it takes average **2.2 seconds and there's only 1 row in the table atm**

My question is how do i speed up mysql queries? I've read about indexes and how they can help improve performance but i do not fully understand how to use them. Any light shed on this topic would help.

Nubcake

Comment: Sometimes something as easy as `service mysqld restart` could make the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes will become very important as your site grows, but they won't help when you have only *one row* in your table and it cannot be the reason why your queries take so long. You seem to have some sort of fundamental problem with your database. Maybe it's a latency issue.

Try starting with some simpler queries like `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1` or even just `SELECT 1` and see if you still get bad performance.

Comment: I wasn't intending on having 1 row but more , I will try what you said , I'm running this on localhost via EasyPHP does that make a difference?

Comment: It takes 1 second when i use SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1

Comment: Nubcake: That's really bad, and that query should be fast even without indexes. What about `SELECT 1`?

Comment: `SELECT 1` should be instant. You seem to have a network problem, or else your server is heavily overloaded.

Comment: I think that could be the problem , without nothing in the script it's an instant response.

Answer (score 1):

Lesser the number of queries, lesser the latency of the system. Try merging queries being made on the same table. For example, your second and third queries can be merged and you can execute

```
INSERT INTO user_info ...... WHERE Valid=1 AND IP= ...
```

Check the number of rows affected to know if a new row was added or not.

Also, do not open/close your sql connection at any point in between. The overheads of establishing a new connection could be high.

Comment: I can try to merge queries but do you think it will shed much time off ? As for closing connections I only close the connection at the end of the script where it needs to be.

Comment: It does look like a configuration issue in that case. Try a reinstallation.

Answer (score -1):

you could make IP Primary Key and Index

Comment: How does that help ? Please explain

Comment: It is faster when it search and update rows when it is indexed.

Comment: Try and run the query in a shell with mysql - and see if its not a php/webserver performance issue.

Comment: I tried making it Primary Key and Index but it still takes 2.2 seconds

Comment: Can you access mysql via some interface or directly to issue a query?